# PrintJob not supported by Swiffy

Tags: flash, printing, actionscript, google-swiffy

I have an ActionScript 1 Flash project, and I'm exporting it with Swiffy.

Swiffy straight up says "The ActionScript class PrintJob is not supported.".

Is there an alternative way just to print the page with ActionScript 1, or post Swiffy conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! There is a solution to it. You can send a javascript call from the flash. requesting a print function.

Now, in your html you should create the print template
The print template can be created by writing html or you can convert your  flash with createJS extension which converts flash into html5 canvas.

After, you have created your template just call, window.print() with you print div visiblity true.

That's it!!! your print is done with Swiffy

Comment: A quick note on the CreateJS comment: You can not convert ActionScript to JavaScript with the Flash » CreateJS extesion/workflow -- only the graphics contents, such as animations and tweens. You would have to rewrite your code.

Comment: Yes, you will have to rewrite the code. But that is the only method to print. Another try could be place your print code in different swiffy div and when button is clicked you can show use window.print() and that should print your page